# How do you show the sum of $1/(n\log n)$ diverges?

Tags: divergent-series

How do you show the sum 
$$\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{1}{n\log n}$$
diverges?

I have tried to use the ratio test but the outcome was inconclusive as the limit was equal to $1$.

Comment: Integral test. Or, Cauchy Condensation test.